# Migration 2010 to 2013 - ContentDB authentication

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, migration, web-application, content-migration

I am migrating a **2010 content DB (classic authentication)** to a **2013 web application (claims authentication)**

The `Test-SPContentDatabase` says that the authentication is different (mounting a classic authentication DB to a Claims authentication web application).

*How can I convert the DB to use Claims Authentication?* 

I do not want to create a classic web application and migrate the DB there.
I need to migrate the old DB to a existing web application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert content database from classic authentication to claim authentication using below mentioned Poweshell commands.

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://yourWebAppUrl
$acc = 'domain\user'
$arguments = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication+SPMigrateUserParameters

#based on scenario above, content DB 0 is the one that was created with the web app, so 1 is the DB that was added with Mount-SPContentDatabase

$arguments.AddDatabaseToMigrate($wa.ContentDatabases[1])
$wa.MigrateUsersToClaims($acc, $true, $arguments)
```